# Understand the csr format

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to undersand how scipy CSR works.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

For example, of the following matrix on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

```
( 0 0 0 0 )
( 5 8 0 0 )
( 0 0 3 0 )
( 0 6 0 0 )
```

it says the CSR representation is the following.

Must V list one row after another with non-zero elements in a row list from left to right?

I can understand `COL_INDEX` is the  column index (column 1 is indexed as 0) corresponding to elements in V.

I don't understand `ROW_INDEX`. Could anybody show me how the `ROW_INDEX` was created from the original matrix? Thanks.

```
   V         = [ 5 8 3 6 ]
   COL_INDEX = [ 0 1 2 1 ]
   ROW_INDEX = [ 0 0 2 3 4 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) manual:

> csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), [shape=(M, N)]) is the standard
>   CSR representation where the column indices for row i are stored in
>   indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]] and their corresponding values are
>   stored in data[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]. If the shape parameter is not
>   supplied, the matrix dimensions are inferred from the index arrays.

`indptr` is the same as `ROW_INDEX` and `indicies` is the same as `COL_INDEX`.

Here is an example of a naive way to create the indices and value array.  Essentially ROW_INDICES[i + 1] is the total number of non-zero entires from row 0 to i inclusive with the last entry being the total number of non-zero entries.

```
ROW_INDICES = [0]
COL_INDICES = []
VALS = []
for i in range(num_rows):
    ROW_INDICES.append(ROW_INDICES[i])
    for j in range(num_cols):
        if m[i, j] > 0:
            ROW_INDICES[i + 1] += 1
            COL_INDICES.append(j)
        VALS.append(m[i, j])
```

Comment: Not clear. Not all csr_matrix() uses `indptr` in the argument.

Comment: `indptr` is the same as `ROW_INDEX` and `indicies` is the same as `COL_INDEX`.  If you read my description below I explain it using the variables you talk about.

Comment: Could you update your answer accordingly explaining how the 5 elements in ROW_INDEX were created? I tried. But I still don't fully understand it. So I can not completely correct it. I also have a question of V added to the original question.

Comment: I put a simple algorithm to show how the indicies are generated hopefulyl this is more clear

Comment: If the value of the first element of ROW_INDICES must be zero, why  it is needed? Isn't it redundant to always save a constant number? Thanks.

Comment: So ROW_INDEX is a misnomer. A name like V_START_INDEX_FOR_ROW is better?

Comment: Something along those lines makes more sense hence why they call it indices and indptr

Answer (score 1):

## `coo` format

I think it's best to start with the `coo` definition.  It's easier to understand, and widely used:

```
In [90]: A = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[5,8,0,0],[0,0,3,0],[0,6,0,0]])                                 
In [91]: M = sparse.coo_matrix(A)
```

The values are stored in 3 attributes:

```
In [92]: M.row                                                                                   
Out[92]: array([1, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [93]: M.col                                                                                   
Out[93]: array([0, 1, 2, 1], dtype=int32)
In [94]: M.data                                                                                  
Out[94]: array([5, 8, 3, 6])
```

We can make a new matrix from those 3 arrays:

```
In [95]: sparse.coo_matrix((_94, (_92, _93))).A                                                  
Out[95]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [5, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [0, 6, 0]])
```

oops, I need to add a shape, since one column is all 0s:

```
In [96]: sparse.coo_matrix((_94, (_92, _93)), shape=(4,4)).A                                     
Out[96]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 8, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 6, 0, 0]])
```

Another way to display this matrix:

```
In [97]: print(M)                                                                                
  (1, 0)    5
  (1, 1)    8
  (2, 2)    3
  (3, 1)    6
```

`np.where(A)` gives the same non-zero coordinates.

```
In [108]: np.where(A)                                                                            
Out[108]: (array([1, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 1]))
```

## conversion to `csr`

Once we have `coo`, we can easily convert it to `csr`.  In fact `sparse` often does that for us:

```
In [98]: Mr = M.tocsr()                                                                          
In [99]: Mr.data                                                                                 
Out[99]: array([5, 8, 3, 6], dtype=int64)
In [100]: Mr.indices                                                                             
Out[100]: array([0, 1, 2, 1], dtype=int32)
In [101]: Mr.indptr                                                                              
Out[101]: array([0, 0, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
```

Sparse does several things - it sorts the indices, sums duplicates, and replaces the `row` with a `indptr` array.  Here it is actually longer than the original, but in general it will be shorter, since it has just one value per row (plus 1).  **But perhaps more important, most of the fast calculation routines, especially matrix multiplication, have been written using the `csr` format.**

I've used this package a lot.  MATLAB as well, where the default definition is in the `coo` style, but the internal storage is `csc` (but not as exposed to users as in `scipy`).  But I've never tried to derive `indptr` from scratch.  I could, but I don't need to.

`csr_matrix` accepts inputs in the `coo` format, but also in the `indptr` etc format.  I wouldn't recommend it, unless you already have those inputs calculated (say from another matrix).  It's more error prone, and probably not much faster.

### Iteration with `indptr`

However sometimes it is useful to iterate on `intptr`, and perform calculations  directly on the `data`.  Often this is faster than working with the provided methods.

For example we can list the nonzero values by row:

```
In [104]: for i in range(Mr.shape[0]): 
     ...:     pt = slice(Mr.indptr[i], Mr.indptr[i+1]) 
     ...:     print(i, Mr.indices[pt], Mr.data[pt]) 
     ...:                                                                                        
0 [] []
1 [0 1] [5 8]
2 [2] [3]
3 [1] [6]
```

Keeping the initial `0` makes this iteration easier.  When the matrix is (10000,90000) there's not much incentive to reduces the size of `indptr` by 1.

## `lil` format

The `lil` format stores the matrix in a similar manner:

```
In [105]: Ml = M.tolil()                                                                         
In [106]: Ml.data                                                                                
Out[106]: array([list([]), list([5, 8]), list([3]), list([6])], dtype=object)
In [107]: Ml.rows                                                                                
Out[107]: array([list([]), list([0, 1]), list([2]), list([1])], dtype=object)

In [110]: for i,(r,d) in enumerate(zip(Ml.rows, Ml.data)): 
     ...:     print(i, r, d) 
     ...:                                                                                        
0 [] []
1 [0, 1] [5, 8]
2 [2] [3]
3 [1] [6]
```

Because of how rows are stored, `lil` actually allows us to fetch a `view`:

```
In [167]: Ml.getrowview(2)                                                                       
Out[167]: 
<1x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 1 stored elements in List of Lists format>
In [168]: for i in range(Ml.shape[0]): 
     ...:     print(Ml.getrowview(i)) 
     ...:                                                                                        

  (0, 0)    5
  (0, 1)    8
  (0, 2)    3
  (0, 1)    6
```