# How to iterate rows in a csr matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I use this code to iterate elements in a csr matrix.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
A = [[0,0,0,0],[5,8,0,0],[0,0,3,0],[0,6,0,0]]
M = sparse.csr_matrix(A)   
print(type(M))

zip2 = lambda x: zip(x[0], x[1])
for i1, i2 in zip2(M.tocsr().nonzero()):
    print(i1, i2, M[i1, i2])
```

But I'd like to iterate rows in this way. Is there a way to do so?

```
for i1 in ...:
   # Do something with i1
   for i2 in ...:
       # Do something with (i1, i2)
```

One way to achieve this is to use `.indices` `.indptr` `.data`. But probably there is something more readable that this way?

Comment: Didn't I just show you how to iterate using `indptr`?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59959653/901925

Comment: If `M` is alread `csr` you don't need another `tocsr` call.   Actually if you look at the `csr` `nonzero` code you'll see it does a `tocoo` and returns the `row` and `col` attributes.  In the other question I also showed that iterating on the rows of the `lil` format is easy.  In fact with `lil` is possible to `getrowview`.

Comment: @hpaulj I missed the part. As I was focusing on what is csr which the first answer answered. So, for an csr matrix, to iterate rows is better to stay with csr or convert to lil then iterate?

Answer (score 0):

One way is convert the csr matrix to array, but that is not good idea if the matrix shape is huge due limited memory.

So the other solution is to let it be CSR and iterate only the rows like this:

```
for i in range(0, M.shape[0]):
    M.getrow(i).toarray()[0]
```